# Issue writing large array to range with vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range, worksheet

I got a runtime error "400" when I try to write an array (30K rows) to a specific range.

Here is how I define my array (simplified version):

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
With ws
    tweets = .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Value2
    'then there is code to filter the tweets array and create a new array called test which contains the filtered values
End With

wb.Sheets("sheets2").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(test, 1), UBound(test, 2)).value = test
```

Running this fails. When I replace "test" with a string like "hello" it does work. Any help would be greatly appreciated (Excel 2013, and I use "Option Explicit").

EDIT: note that my target for writing the array is not "sheets2" but a sheet that has been dynamically created during a for loop. Thus I use sheetname(i) instead of "sheets2" in my real code. Don't know if that might create the issue. Also, I sometimes got a 1004 error and just half of the data is written to the sheet... very strange.

Comment: Where do you declare and assign a value to your `test` variable?  (You mention it in a comment, but you haven't shown us the code.)

Comment: I mentioned it so that people there would not ask me why I dont just copy the range directly without using an array. Actually, my code also fails when I try with "tweets" directly. So you can replace "test" with "tweets": the problem remains.

Comment: When it crashes, what are the dimensions of `test`?  (I.e. is it `1 To 30000, 1 To 500`, or is it `0 To 32167, 0 To 11`, or is it `1 To 31231, 1 To 17, 1 To 321`, etc?)

Comment: Consider that "test = tweets", that will be simpler. UBound(tweets, 1) = 10611, UBound(tweets, 2) = 13. LBound(tweets, 1) and LBound(tweets, 2) are both = 1

Comment: Error 400 is a strange one to get - does the message say "Form already displayed; can't show modally" (That's the only error 400 I have found by googling it.)  (P.S.  I have been running your code, changing `test` to `tweets`, and I have yet to find a way to make it fail.)

Comment: There is not message. Just a simple "400" is thrown. Don't know why it works perfectly whith a simpe string and fails with a complex array. I used "Dim tweets() as Variant" so there should not be issues with the values it contains...

Comment: I'm stumped. (Certainly not a size issue - I was testing with 30,123 rows and 100 columns without any troubles.)

Comment: I found what causes the error. Some cells begin with a "=" and that throws a 404. Do you know the best way to make excel accept these? I don't wish to remove them

Comment: I think the only thing you can do is loop through the array and do a `If Left(test(i, j),1) = "=" Then test(i,j) = "'" & test(i,j)`.  (Silly Excel! It's trying to be nice and is guessing that you are putting a formula into the cell despite using the `Value` property, and guessing your intentions incorrectly. :( )

Comment: Another solution could be to pre-format the destination range to `Range.NumberFormat = "@"` (text) and then write the array to this range. Strange enough, with cells entered as preformated text, excel puts the `'` sign in front of the `'=bla`. However, after writing from array the `'` is gone.